# jaxb - how to know when eventhandler is called (during validation)

Tags: jaxb, eventhandler

I am parsing XML with JAXB and have created an event handler that will display errors if there were issues on validation.

The event handler is called and prints out errors; How do I throw an exception if the event handler is called (after printout?)

In the code, I have no idea when the event handler is called, it is simply called on a validation error; I need the ability to move a file to a /dir/ after the event handler returns.

---

My event handler looks like this:

```
import base.helper.HelperBase;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;

/**
 *
 */
@Component
public class MyValidationEventHandler extends HelperBase implements ValidationEventHandler {

    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "\n---");
        System.out.println("EVENT");
        System.out.println("\nEVENT");
        System.out.println("SEVERITY:  " + event.getSeverity());
        System.out.println("MESSAGE:  " + event.getMessage());
        System.out.println("LINKED EXCEPTION:  " + event.getLinkedException());
        System.out.println("LOCATOR");
        System.out.println("    LINE NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getLineNumber());
        System.out.println("    COLUMN NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getColumnNumber());
        System.out.println("    OFFSET:  " + event.getLocator().getOffset());
        System.out.println("    OBJECT:  " + event.getLocator().getObject());
        System.out.println("    NODE:  " + event.getLocator().getNode());
        System.out.println("    URL:  " + event.getLocator().getURL());
        new Exception("fail");
        return true;
    }
}
```

When processing, my code looks like this:

```
    private void processXmlFile(String file) throws Exception {
        // todo: test for file existence, get size, print stats

        try {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Processing: " + file);
            SchemaFactory sf = null;
            Schema schema = null;

            JAXBContext jctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("mypackage.jaxb");
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jctx.createUnmarshaller();

            if (validate) {
                sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
                schema = sf.newSchema(new File(xsd));
                unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
                eventHandler.setLogger(logger);
                unmarshaller.setEventHandler(eventHandler);
            }


            JAXBElement<MyType> mytype = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File(file)), MyType.class);
            MyType ct = mytype.getValue();

        } catch (Exception e) { // if find a problem file, just move it out of the way and keep processing
            // if the event handler is called, I want to throw an exception and do something here.
            // move file to failed
            fileUtils.moveFile(config.getErrorDir(), file);
            // on an unmarshall failure, this exception is not thrown/caught because the event handler handles things and returns true


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read [How to Throw Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html).

In your event handler you need to `throw()` an `Exception` perhaps with something like:

```
throw new ValidationException();  //  throw exeption
```

Instead of:

```
new Exception("fail");  //  create exception but do nothing with it?
```

And you would define your `ValidationException` as:

```
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {

  public ValidationException(final String s) {
    super(s);
  }
```

Change:

```
public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
```

To:

```
public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) throws ValidationException {
```

In `processXmlFile()` we now need something like:

```
catch (ValidationException e) { 
  // catch more specific exception first
  fileUtils.moveFile(config.getErrorDir(), file);
catch (Exception e) {
  // deal with any other exceptions ...
}
```